# Есть ли способ получить #text

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Использую anglesharp для парсинга, нужно получить без обозначений текст
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так, но выдает null

```
  document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(html));
            foreach(var doc in document.QuerySelectorAll("div.inner-tab__item"))
            {
                if(doc.TextContent.Contains("Пляж"))
                {
                    var a = doc.QuerySelectorAll("#text").FirstOrDefault();
                    Console.WriteLine("l");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить доступ к текстовым узлам с помощью свойства `ChildNodes` или метода `Descendents`.

```
foreach (var div in document.QuerySelectorAll("div.inner-tab__item"))
{
    if (div.TextContent.Contains("Пляж"))
    {
        foreach (var node in div.Descendents<IText>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[" + node.TextContent.Trim() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, по пути к текстовому узлу, показанному на скриншоте, присутствуют ещё несколько других, пустых и заполненных. Я добавил в вывод квадратные скобки, чтобы было понятно их наличие.

Нужно именно узел `p` найти, чтобы получить нужное значение.